# How to write rule for checking alphabets or numbers in moodle form fields

Tags: regex, validation, moodle

I want to write an `addrule` for **moodle** form that check if the field contain `alphabets or numbers`.

I tried like this:

```
$mform->addRule('title', 'Invalid data', 'regex', '/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+$/');
```

But this is not working. how can I make working this?

Please help me..

Comment: If you want to check if a string contains a number or alphabet, try using `/[a-zA-Z0-9]/`, or, to also match any Unicode letters and numbers, `/[\p{L}\p{N}]/u`.

Comment: Check this one: `$mform->addRule('title', 'regex', 'Invalid data', '/[a-zA-Z0-9]/');`.

Comment: Can you post some sample data of what is or is not matching?  What flavor of regex are we talking about here?

Comment: I mean, the addRule validation using regex is not working for me

Comment: @next2u were you able to check numbers

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of regex. but you can use the following code from the moodle lib.

```
$mform->addRule('title', 'Only Numerics Allowed', 'numeric', null, 'client');
```

or

```
$mform->addRule('title', 'Only Numerics Allowed', 'numeric', null, 'server');
```

Thanks,